# Parse text response from http request in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I am trying to fetch data from an APU but as response I am getting the plain text. I want to read all text line by line.

This is the `url` variable: http://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt?t=23052017073640

First snippet:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = "https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt?t=23052017073640"
request = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(request.text,"lxml")
for line in soup:
    print line
    break
```

**Result**: It prints out the entire text

Second snippet:

```
request = requests.get(url)
for line in request.text():
    print line
    break
```

**Result**: It prints out 1 character

```
request = requests.get(url)
requestText = request.text()
allMf = requestText.splitlines()
```

**Result**: Exception: 'unicode' object is not callable

I have tried few more cases but not able to read text line by line.

Comment: Are you sure that in the second snippet you loop over `request.text()` and not over `request.text`? And if yes, it should throw an exception because `request.text` is a property, not a method. Therefore, you don't need `()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`request.text` is a property and not a method, `request.text` returns a unicode string, `request.text()` throws the error `'unicode' object is not callable`.

```
for line in request.text.splitlines():
    print line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = "https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt?t=23052017073640"
request = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(request.text,"lxml")

# soup.text is to get the returned text
# split function, splits the entire text into different lines (using '\n') and stores in a list. You can define your own splitter.
# each line is stored as an element in the allLines list.
allLines = soup.text.split('\n') 

for line in allLines: # you iterate through the list, and print the single lines
    print(line)
    break # to just print the first line, to show this works
```

Comment: Can you explain your code and why it solves the issue? *Code only* answers are often not that helpful.

Comment: Added the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = "https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt?t=23052017073640"
request = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(request.text,"lxml")
for line in soup:
    print line.text
    break
```